# Add a counter when adding products CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

In my table categories I have a row called count that I want to update every time a new product is created but I'm new to this cakephp and I do not know how to play with 2 controllers at the same time.

It is add in my Products controller: (is default add creating with bake)

```
   public function add()
    {
        $product = $this->Products->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->getData());

            if ($this->Products->save($product)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The product has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The product could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $categorys = $this->Products->Categorys->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('product', 'categorys'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['product']);
    }
```

Each product has a related category.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `CounterCache` behavior in the [**Cookbook**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html)

All you have to do is attach it to your model and tell it the name of the column where you want to store the count (I assume here that is called `product_count`)

```
class CategoriesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('CounterCache', [
            'Products' => ['product_count']
        ]);
    }
}
```